# Function parameter constrained by Equatable binary operator cannot be applied

Tags: swift, generics

I can't see where I am going wrong here.

```
private func check<A: Equatable, B: Equatable>(_ value: (A, B)) {
    let message = String(describing: value.0) + " does not equal " + String(describing: value.1)
    XCTAssert(value.0 == value.1, message)
}
```

Error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'A' and 'B'

Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)
Swift 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Equatable` protocol is defined as

```
public protocol Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}
```

which means that for a conforming type `A` there is a `==` operator 
taking two operands of type `A`. In other words, you can
compare a value of type `A` with another value of the *same type* A –
but not necessarily with a value of a different type `B` (even if 
that is `Equatable`).

Your function

```
func check<A: Equatable, B: Equatable>(_ value: (A, B))
```

takes a tuple where both members are values of equatable – but possibly
different – types, therefore the compiler complains on the expression

```
value.0 == value.1
```

As an example, both `Int` and `String` conform to `Equatable`, so you could call

```
check((123, "abc"))
```

but those values cannot be compared.

What you perhaps want is

```
func check<A: Equatable>(_ value: (A, A)) { ... }
```

where both tuple members are of the *same* equatable type `A`.